# Prevent HTML tags from getting automatically escaped when echoing in a Symfony view

Tags: php, symfony1, escaping, symfony-1.4

I have a database that takes in data from a WYWSWIG enabled textarea, which basically means a lot of the text area is HTML tag encoded such as instead of having :

```
info data text info data text stored in the table column, I have <p>info data<strong>info data</strong><em>text</em></p> encoded in there.
```

Upon executing the db query (using Doctrine), this information is retained in my action, and it is wrapped in a variable that is passed into the template. At this point, upon rendering, the tags are retained...To illustrate, the text is not rendered with the desired HTML markup effect but rather with the tags as it is. This obviously implies that there is an character escape happening.

I am not sure how to mitigate this issue. But I did find a makeshift solution that can suffice for the time being. I execute the Doctrine query in my template rather than the action. In this case, there is no escaping happening, and the desired HTML markup renders itself. The obvious implication from this is that when the query variable is being passed from the action to the template, there is some kind of internal Symfony character escaping taking place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony wraps all variables passed to the view in [`sfOutputEscaper`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfOutputEscaper) instances by default.  To get the unescaped value, echo `$var->getRawValue()` in your view.